# CSS Cursor Not Working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using [this script](https://allinworld99.blogspot.com/2015/01/php-profile-image-upload-script-change.html) to power a profile image upload function on my site. It displays an image with an overlay banner across the bottom:

[image: capture]

When mousing over that overlay banner, the CSS "cursor: pointer" declaration works fine in the browsers I've tested *except* for Chrome. With Chrome for both Windows and Mac, the pointer cursor only appears on the edges of that overlay. When the cursor hovers over the "Change Photo" text, the cursor reverts back to arrow.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="imgChange">
  Change Photo
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="16">
</div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#imgChange input[type="file"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

I've put together a page demonstrating the issue [here](http://dev.linkstac.kr/cursor_test.html).

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure on why this problem occurs, but it appears setting the hight of the input element to `60px` resolves the issue:

```
#imgChange input[type="file"] {
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;     /* <-- */
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The height of the element is `30px` but for some reason the double height needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the `opacity: 0;` of the `#imgChange input[type="file"]` you will see why :)